# Is NAnt in the dead pool?

Tags: nant

I know NAnt sees frequent use (well, I always use it for *my* CI builds) but there has been no new official release since December 2007. Is the project receiving active development any more or is it dead-pooled? It worries me that if I carry on using it, and it stops tracking the latest version of .NET, I'll eventually be left with a massive job when it comes to upgrading systems to a version of the framework that it can't build.

Has everyone else gone over to some other tool like MSBuild these days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the official blog - NAnt’s not dead, it was just resting

https://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/nant/2010/04/05/nants-not-dead-it-was-just-resting/

Comment: This URL has meanwhile become unreachable (probably as a part of SourceForge's hosted apps retirement).

Comment: (web archive)
https://web.archive.org/web/20100522194307/http://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/nant/2010/04/05/nants-not-dead-it-was-just-resting/

Comment: Thanks, but the fact that the posting can only be found on `web.archive.org` unfortunately doesn't speak for the current alive-status of the project.

Answer (score 7):

It seems as if development will be more active in the near future. This is from [a message from the developers mailing list from 05 Mar 2010](http://www.mail-archive.com/nant-developers%40lists.sourceforge.net/msg07834.html):

> since we are in an early stage of
>   getting drive on nant again, I want to
>   ask if we could moving away from CVS.
>
> My first proposal is to switch to
>   subversion.
>
> ...

I'm also using NAnt for quite some time, and while I was a little bit concerned about the project being dead, so far NAnt did its job very well.

**Update**: NAnt 0.90 Beta 1 was released on April 17, 2010

Comment: NAnt 0.90 (Final) has been released May 8, 2010