# .Net/C# Build Tool - Is NAnt a preferred tool?

Tags: c#, build-automation, nant

I'm about to set up an automatic build of a .net/C# project.

I've searched the net quite a bit, and there are a lot of references to this tool called 'NAnt'.

My questions are:

- Is NAnt considered a good tool for this, is it still used?
- Are there other toos that are the de facto standard for such a task?

From the information on the projects's sourceforge page, it doesn't seem to have been much development going on the lates years. The same applies to the NAntContrib project.

Thanks!

Comment: NAnt and MSBuild are the 2 primary tools, Team Foundation Server's build agents are built fully (or mostly) off of MSBuild.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476163/nant-or-msbuild-which-one-to-choose-and-when/476224#476224 for a comparison of NAnt/MSBuild. Summary: depends on your preferences (pros and cons for each). To answer your other question: yes, it is still used.

Answer (score 7):

NAnt is widely used and has good support.

Visual studio comes with its own build tool - MSBuild, that is built into visual studio (project and solution files are MSBuild scripts). It has a large support base and multiple extensions with community [build tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).

Comment: Actually, it is not *part* of Visual Studio per se. It is part of the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1):

[MS Build Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) is another option to automate the build processes.

Answer (score 1):

- Is NAnt considered a good tool for this, is it still used?

NAnt is still used. I have used it for automated deployment of an ASP.NET web application and related services and database.

- Are there other tools that are the de facto standard for such a task?

MSBuild is widely used. An advantage over NAnt is that it is included in .NET 2.0+. I also like the array-like features and batching: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473%28VS.80%29.aspx.

---

See also this related question: [NAnt or MSBuild, which one to choose and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476163/nant-or-msbuild-which-one-to-choose-and-when).

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for myself, yes NAnt is still used. I have a standard build script that I can easily add to any new project. I do this for any new code that I am planning on keeping around for a while.

NAnt is mature and widely used in many projects. A big part of its appeal is its extensibility via custom tasks.

The project does seem to have stalled, but apparently it is still alive and kicking, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413202/is-nant-in-the-dead-pool). There is some talk of a roadmap for the fuuture, and a new version as well.